# sed + removes all leading and trailing whitespace from each line on solaris system

Tags: perl, sed, awk, solaris

I have a Solaris machine  (SunOSsu1a 5.10 Generic_142900-15 sun 4vsparcSUNW,Netra-T2000).

The following sed syntax removes all leading and trailing whitespace from each line (I need to remove whitespace because it causes application problems).

```
        sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' orig_file > new_file
```

But I noticed that sed also removes the "t" character from the end of each line.

Please advise how to fix the sed syntax/command in order to remove only the leading and trailing whitespace from each line  (the solution can be also with Perl or AWK).

Examples (take a look at the last string - set_host)

1)

Original line before running sed command

```
   pack/configuration/param[14]/action:set_host
```

another example (before I run sed)

```
   +/etc/cp/config/Network-Configuration/Network-Configuration.xml:/cp-pack/configuration/param[8]/action:set_host
```

2)

the line after I run the sed command

```
   pack/configuration/param[14]/action:set_hos
```

another example (after I run sed)

```
   +/etc/cp/config/Network-Configuration/Network-Configuration.xml:/cp-pack/configuration/param[8]/action:set_hos
```

Comment: That works fine for me using `GNU sed` on OS X: `echo '   set_host   ' | gsed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' > newfile ; cat -e newfile` gives `set_host$` (removed whitespace, kept the `t`).

Comment: did U run it on solaris machine ? ( anyway I not have gsed in my solaris machine )

Comment: No, that's on OS X. You could check the version of `sed` you're using - in my experience there's differences between the `BSD` and `GNU` versions in terms of syntax. I'm not sure what Solaris uses, but you could check if there's a `GNU sed` available to you (probably `gsed`).

Comment: Perhaps sed doesn't recognize tab character `\t`(You would have lost t character in the beginning too. Try `s/^\s*\(.*\)\s*$/\1/` if you system supports `\s`

Comment: It seems pretty clear that your `sed` doesn't support `\t`, so it treats the `t` as part of the character class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just occurred to me you can use a character class:

```
sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//;s/[[:space:]]*$//'
```

This happens in your `sed` and gnu sed with the `--posix` option because (evidently) posix interprets the `[ \t]` as a space, a `\`, or a `t`. You can fix this by putting a literal tab instead of `\t`, easiest way is probably <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>. If that doesn't work, put the patterns in a file (with the literal tabs) and use `sed -f patterns.sed oldfile > newfile`.

Comment: please give me example about the update sed command ( what need to fix in the sed syntax ?)

Comment: The syntax is the same, just instead of typing `\t`, type `ctrl-v` followed by the `tab` key.

Comment: Perfect! This worked for me on FreeBSD 9.1-RELEASE. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As @aix noted, the problem is undoubtedly that your `sed` doesn't understand `\t`.  While the GNU `sed` does, many propriety Unix flavors don't.  HP-UX is one and I believe Solaris is too.  If you can't install a GNU `sed` I'd look to Perl:

```
perl -pi.old -e 's{^\s+}{};s{\s+$}{}' file
```

...will trim one or more leading white space (^\s+) [spaces and/or tabs] together with trailing white space (\s+$) updating the file in situ leaving a backup copy as "file.old".